# How to change the content of vertexbuffer used in glDrawArrays method in opengles

Tags: opengl-es, 3d

I have some triangle polygons and drawing them in a traditional way:
(android-java code)

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, i, j);
```

I want to update the vertex coordinates of the triangles. All of the tutorials I've found use an initial vertex data then only apply transformations to them. I need to change each vertex coordinate independently.

I change the content of the array which is used to create the related vertexbuffer but it doesn't make any change on the screen. Rebuilding the vertexbuffer on eachframe doesn't seem to be right way I guess.

Can you point out any example source code at least, if you know any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`glBufferSubData`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml). Basically, you update the contents of your array just as you've described, then you call `glBufferSubData` to update the vertex buffer object with the new values.

This assumes you're modifying only a relatively small subset of the data. If you're modifying most of the data, it's generally better to just call `glBufferData` again instead.

Comment: Probably you are right but I couldn't manage to work it. Do you know if it is required to do some preparations about glgenbuffers and glbindbuffer before using glbuffersubdata?

Comment: @emre: No, I don't recall doing anything unusual/special to use `glbufferSubData`.

Comment: I do smt similar to this(if it seems clear)
 public void draw(GL11 gl) {
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
  
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
     
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  
  vertices[0] += 5;
  gl.glBufferSubData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , 0, 4, vertexBuffer);  
 }
 I'll continue to struggle and inform if I can manage

Comment: @JerryCoffin You fail to point out the fact that `glBufferSubData` is only advisable when a small portion of the buffer requires an update. Otherwise, `glBufferData` should be used. Source: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices#Size_of_a_VBO.2FIBO

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: At least as I read it, that was the whole point of the question. He's already submitted the data, is modifying a few specific pieces, and wants to avoid re-sending all the data.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think I'm just reading it differently then. He never really clarifies if the triangles in question are what his entire scene consists of or not. I think it's generally good to be thorough regardless.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: Fair enough--caveat added.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that most part of my problem is java-android related. @jerry proposed the right solution to the main idea in my question but I'll adress the java-android related parts of the problems:

First; method signatures in Renderer interface of Android offers you a GL10 object as parameter but some of the methods you need are in opengl-es1.1 so you need to cast gl object.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
   GL11 gl11 = (GL11)gl;
```

Ofcourse if the device doesn't support opengl-es1.1 your code won't work but that's out of our topic.

My other problem was about the differences in java implementation of opengl-es. In java you create a related Buffer object, which is a native java class in java.nio package, and fill inside of this buffer with an array you specified.

```
public static FloatBuffer createFloatBuffer(float[] array){     
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer fbuf = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    fbuf.put(array);
    fbuf.position(0);
    return fbuf;
}
```

After this part you have nothing to do with the array object. You need to update the buffer object. You can update the content of buffer by using `put(index, value)` method of related buffer class.

Here is the draw() method of an object we want to draw. `vertexBuffer` is a `FloatBuffer` object. You can get the idea I think from this snippet.

```
public void draw(GL11 gl) {

    vertexBuffer.put(index, floatValue);
    gl.glBufferSubData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexBuffer.capacity(),vertexBuffer);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

}
```

You can correct me if there are misleading points..

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is create multiple vertex buffers on initialization and then just bind to different ones using glBindBuffer()

Comment: I didn't understand how this will work. I want to change the content of each vertex, not switch between arrays.

Comment: There is no reason to do this. If he is having issues with just one VBO, then telling him to use multiple isn't going to solve anything.